# Element <cache> does not allow nested <searchable> elements

Tags: java, spring, maven, jboss, ehcache

When I am trying to use ehcache with an old war, I am getting the following error in JBoss 7.1.0EAP server:

```
Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Error configuring from input stream. Initial cause was null:10: Element <cache> does not allow nested <searchable> elements.
        at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory.parseConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:157)
        at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory.parseConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:101)
        ... 94 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: null:10: Element <cache> does not allow nested <searchable> elements.
        at net.sf.ehcache.config.BeanHandler.createChild(BeanHandler.java:121)
        at net.sf.ehcache.config.BeanHandler.startElement(BeanHandler.java:73)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
        at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory.parseConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:155)
        ... 95 more
```

My pom.xml has the following

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
</dependency>
```

What am I doing wrong

Comment: The issue is your using a '<searchable> elements' on the cache.xml, maybe the version does not allow this.

Comment: This certainly is a missconfiguration of ehcache.